# Diferenciar tipos de elementos HTML en JavaScript o jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo una serie de `labels` en mi vista `JSP`. Cada `label` muestra una unidad de medida y en caso de querer editarla se reemplaza via javascript por un `input` via boton.

**NOTA:** tanto las labels como los input son elementos con class="CCC_UNIDAD" para iterarlos posteriormente. El `html` resultante simplificado quedaria algo asi:

```
<label class="CCC_UNIDAD">%</label>
<input class="CCC_UNIDAD">
<input class="CCC_UNIDAD" value="$">
<label class="CCC_UNIDAD">€</label>
```

```
$.each($(".CCC_UNIDAD"), function (index, value) {
    var valor = value.textContent === undefined 
                                  ? (value.value === undefined ? "" : value.value) 
                                  : value.textContent; 
    alert("VALOR = " + valor);
});
```

Como véis, en el snippet, intento coger el valor de la label (`value.textContent`), si no lo tiene busco el valor del input `value.value` pero no esta funcionando correctamente.

¿Cómo puedo **diferenciar que tipo de elemento** es la variable `value` para así coger el atributo correspondiente a cada tipo?

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar tu html para hacer el ejemplo en vivo y poderte ayudar mejor?

Comment: @WilfredoP hecho, pero la verdad esque tiene poco que ver, es una pregunta conceptual sobre los objetos en javascript/jquery

Comment: Es un error o algunos son labels y otros inputs?

Comment: Por favor @Cesar lee la pregunta con atencion

Comment: Esa mala costumbre que tengo de ir de lleno al código....

Comment: input no lleva tag de cierre.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En primer lugar como menciona @rnrneverdies el HTML no está bien formado. Las etiquetas input no llevan tag de cierre sino que son autocerradas.

La forma correcta debe ser:

```
<label class="CCC_UNIDAD">%</label>
<input class="CCC_UNIDAD" value=""/>
<input class="CCC_UNIDAD" value="$" />
<label class="CCC_UNIDAD">€</label>
```

Luego para obtener el valor o el texto puedes usar el operador `||`

```
$(".CCC_UNIDAD").each(function(){
    alert("VALOR = " + ($(this).val() || $(this).text()));
});
```

Finalmente en tu caso todo quedaría como el sgte snippet

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".CCC_UNIDAD").each(function(){
        alert("VALOR = " + ($(this).val() || $(this).text()));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="CCC_UNIDAD">%</label>
<input class="CCC_UNIDAD" value=""/>
<input class="CCC_UNIDAD" value="$" />
<label class="CCC_UNIDAD">€</label> 
<button>Hazme clic me para probar</button>
```

Comment: el html de la pregunta ya estaba corregido, gracias por la respuesta, habia encontrado el nodeName pero no me parecia muy elegante, gracias!!!

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad `nodeName`, aquí te dejo un ejemplo.

(deberás abrir la consola F12 para ver los resultados)

nota: el elemento input, en html5, no lleva tag de cierre. Se inicializa como se ve abajo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($(".CCC_UNIDAD"), function(index, value) {
    if (value.nodeName === "INPUT") {
      console.log(value.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="CCC_UNIDAD">Label1</label>
<input class="CCC_UNIDAD" value="v1">
<input class="CCC_UNIDAD" value="v2">
<label class="CCC_UNIDAD">Label2</label>
```

Answer (score -3):

Si quieres saber el tag del objeto puedes hacer esto (con tu código):

```
var objetos = document.getElementsByClassName('CCC_UNIDAD');

for(index in objetos){
  console.log(objetos[index].tagName);
}
```

El .tagName te dice si es 'DIV', 'INPUT', 'TABLE', etc ...

Comment: Esto debería ser un comentario, ya que no es un respuesta concreta.

Comment: menudo troll estás hecho

Comment: No es ser troll, en StackOverflow existe un codigo de como preguntar y como contestar, lo que hago es que el site tenga calidad ya que vendo de SO ingles. La verdad disculpa si es una molestia o me vez como un troll pero te recomiendo pasar por la ayuda y sabrás porque coloco comentarios en las preguntas/respuestas que considero que están mal hechas o falta información.

Comment: Eugenio, @WilfredoP tiene razon, ademas, no responde a mi pregunta, porque si lees atentamente, veras que necesito saber si el objeto que itero es un `input` o una `label`, pero con `typeof value` me va a devolver siempre `object`

Comment: ademas si borras la respuesta ahora conseguiras +6 rep y la medalla  `presión popular`

Comment: xDDDD total ya ...

Comment: y no consiguió la medalla "Presión popular" =( ...

Comment: @Elenasys él sabrá....